# How to see the list of uninstalled applications?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, adb, system, system-apps

Is there a way to see the **list of uninstalled applications** (**which are also removed from the list provided by** `Google Play`) or the **history of app installations**? Does `adb` support any operations like this?

Comment: No, I don't think Play provide such info. Maybe it is possible to obtain it from phone...

Comment: Yes, so far I could not find a way. But I think there should be some log regarding app installation/uninstallation. @Suncatcher